# Quero fazer uma espécie de parallax horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parallax

Quero fazer com que ao clicar no botão "ver mais" a página "deslize" para a esquerda e surja outra vindo da direita. Peguei alguns exemplos e estava tentando montar por minha conta mas não obtive sucesso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portifólio Augusto Seabra</title>

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="" sizes="32x32">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="" alt="icone">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" id="aumentaFonte"> A+ </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" id="diminuiFonte"> A- </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="container" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="caixa-container">
      <div id="textos-container d-flex">
        <p class="lead"> Olá, meu nome é </p>
        <h1 class="display-3">Augusto</h1>
        <p class="lead"> eu gosto de criar & codificar! </p>
        <p class=text-center><a href="#qualificacoes" id="botao">Ver mais</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div id="qualificacoes1">
   <h3 class="display-5">Conhecimentos</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>
     HTML
    </li>
    <li>
     CSS
    </li>
    <li>
     JavaScript
    </li>
    <li>
     jQuery
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> -->

  </div>
  <footer class="bg-dark d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
    <a href="">
      <img src="" alt="Bandeira do Brasil">
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img src="" alt="Bandeira dos Estados Unidos">
    </a>
  </footer>

  <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Você quer dizer um carrossel? Onde entra o paralaxe na história

Comment: Compartilhe um exemplo de site que faz isso para entendermos melhor sua ideia.